# Ignored 5.0 OTA update on nexus 4 now can't get it back

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

I ignored the 5.0 update when it came over the air a couple of months back because I didn't want it at that time, and now I do want to update, but it's nowhere to be found on my phone. I go to settings -> about phone -> system update but it just shows that "system is up to date" even when I click check for update. I'm running 4.4.4.

I know that I could go and manually do the update but it seems ridiculous that there is no way to get the OTA update back? I don't want to have to do a bunch of manual work.

Is there no way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Related: [What is Google's OTA phase deployment strategy?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/what-is-googles-ota-phase-deployment-strategy/57550#57550) & [How can I force my Nexus One to upgrade to the official Gingerbread without waiting for the formal OTA update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6334/how-can-i-force-my-nexus-one-to-upgrade-to-the-official-gingerbread-without-wait)

Comment: Alright but I've already gotten the OTA once and ignored it so I need to force it somehow to get it again. Clearly all phones already have the 5.0 OTA because that was like 2 months ago so waiting for another batch of roll-outs isn't going to work. And the second link is just manual.

Comment: Yes, but they are related to your question. I didn't say they were the answer, which is why I posted them as a comment, and didn't suggest to close this as a duplicate. Also related: [Why can't I update my Nexus 4 to Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88305/why-cant-i-update-my-nexus-4-to-lollipop?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have found sources {[1](http://www.howtogeek.com/138200/how-to-force-an-android-device-to-find-a-system-update/)} {[2](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-force-any-android-device-to-download-latest-ota-system-update/)} {[3](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1321/force_an_ota_update_on_your_android_nexus_device)} that say doing the following can *force an OTA*, but YMMV.

- Go to `Settings > Apps`
- scroll down to `Google Services Framework`
- select that app
  [image]
- Clear data
- Clear cache
- Force stop
- Now go in to `Settings > About > System Update` and check for an update.

Comment: hmm I tried all the slightly different variations from your sources multiple times and it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for the response though it was a good try.

Comment: Your only options then... Wait, or flash manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a reboot (or power cycle) or two can trigger the update prompt again.

For Nexus owners, the [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) is indispensable.  It can do a whole lot more than you need, but... it can get the job done.

To flash an updated OS, choose to "flash stock" then make **SURE** you click "no wipe" if you want to ensure it doesn't erase your personal data.  You pick your target version, then it wipes the system partition and replaces it with the updated Android version (and then on first boot it'll do all sorts of upgrading to update your apps and data).