# Will Android Lollipop be pushed to Nexus 7 device again

Tags: nexus-7, 5.0-lollipop, android-versions

I received a push update for android 5 and was not installed as selected later as the timing of the notification wasn't the right time.  My device now says the system is up to date

Just wondering, will the update to android 5 be pushed again and when is likely timing?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Ignored 5.0 OTA update on nexus 4 now can't get it back](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93825/ignored-5-0-ota-update-on-nexus-4-now-cant-get-it-back/93828#comment117599_93828)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to flash the factory image yourself. See the instructions and links to all Nexus factory images at https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Note that this procedure will not preserve your data as may be the case with OTA push updates.